# How to create a new entity with RELAX NG schema in DocBook V5.0

Tags: docbook, dtd, relaxng, docbook-5, xml

With DocBook V4.x and DTD, I could create an entity with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd" [

<!ENTITY mdash   "&#8212;">

]>
<article>
...
<title>Em dash</title>

<para>The em dash is perhaps the most versatile punctuation mark.
Depending on the context, the em dash can take the place of commas,
parentheses, or colons&mdash;in each case to slightly different effect.</para>
...
</article>
```

How could I do the same with DocBook V5.0 using the RELAX NG schema?:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<article xmlns='http://docbook.org/ns/docbook' version='5.0' xml:lang='en'>
...
<title>Em dash</title>
<para>The em dash is perhaps the most versatile punctuation mark.
Depending on the context, the em dash can take the place of commas,
parentheses, or colons&mdash;in each case to slightly different effect.</para>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can’t define general entities using RELAX NG. Entities are a DTD thing. You either need to use an internal DTD subset (as in your first code example) or just use tools that are hardcoded to recognize the entities (e.g. as Web browsers are).